# How to test computed property that returns PromiseArray in Ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a computed property that asks server for user data and then the other one that computes number of users. To propagate changes into the template, I'm using DS.PromiseArray wrapper. With this wrapper, I can't find an easy way to test this property.

```
  // model
  users: computed('name', function () {
    let name = get(this, 'name');
    return DS.PromiseArray.create({
      promise: this.store.query('user', { name })
    });
  }),

  numberOfUsers: computed('users', function () {
    return get(this, 'users.length') || 0;
  }),

  // ....

  test('numberOfUsers returns correct number', function (assert) {
    let model = this.subject({
      store: EmberObject.create({
        query() {
          return Promise.resolve([
            { name: 'Thomas' },
            { name: 'Thomas' },
            { name: 'Thomas' },
          ]);
        }
      }),
      name: 'Thomas',
    });

    assert.equal(model.get('numberOfUsers'), 3);
  });
```

This test fails with 0 !== 3. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `model.get('users')` is a promise, `model.get('numberOfUsers')` will not be 3 until the Promise resolves.  In your test, you're immediately calling `model.get('numberOfUsers')`, and that is using the initial value of `model.get('users')`, which is an unresolved promise.

To get it to work, you could call `users` and put your `assert` inside the `then` of that returned promise:

```
model.get('users').then((user) => {
  assert.equal(model.get('numberOfUsers'), 3);
})
```

A couple of side notes:

It is conventional in Ember to do your data fetching in the [Route's model hook](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/3.0/classes/Route/methods/model?anchor=model), not in a component like this.

Also, there's no need to manually create a `PromiseArray` in your application code, because an Ember Data `query` returns a type of Promise Array already.  So you can just `return this.store.query('user', { name });` (If you do this, you'll have to change your test query stub to generate a `PromiseArray`).

Comment: Thanks, also using new testing api it's possible to await in the test.